# Floor plan overlay hiding behind Map view regardless of z-index setting

Tags: google-maps-api-3, overlay

I'm working on applying a floor plan overlay to a building's satellite view in Google Maps.  To do this, I've followed [this example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple), but the overlay is hiding behind the map panes no matter the z-index setting.

I'm using the `OverlayView()` function, of which the onAdd function is defined

```js
overlayFloorPlan.prototype.onAdd = function(){
  // Create the DIV and set some basic attributes.
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
  div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.zIndex = '100000'; //this number makes no difference

  // Create an IMG element and attach it to the DIV.
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = this.image_;
  img.style.width = '100%';
  img.style.height = '100%';
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  img.style.opacity = "0.7";
  //img.style.zIndex = "100000";
  div.appendChild(img);

  // Set the overlay's div_ property to this DIV
  this.div_ = div;

  // We add an overlay to a map via one of the map's panes.
  // We'll add this overlay to the overlayImage pane.
  var panes = this.getPanes();
  panes.overlayImage.appendChild(div); 
}
```

What is strange is I can see the overlay image for a split second during page load, then it disappears.

To make things even stranger, this exact code renders fine on my dev machine at work, but not on my local machine at home.  I can remote in and see the overlay as expected.  Both machines run identical up to date versions of Ubuntu, differing only in kernel versions.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have the DIV containing the image absolutely positioned but it does not have a size specified.
The image is also absolutely positioned and has a height and width of 100%, but 100% of what? Since the DIV does not have a size the image size is 100% of nothing. Either give the DIV a size or the image a specific size and it should appear.

You should also use the overlayLayer pane instead of overlayImage.